# Terraform Output variable to use for different resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created azure application insights and output the instrumentation key.

FileName: tfapp.tf

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "core_application_insights" {
   name                = "${var.environment_name}-test-service-aai-${var.company_tag}"
   resource_group_name = "${var.environment_name}-aai-${var.company_tag}"
   location            = "${var.location}"
   application_type    = "${var.aai_application_type}"
 }

 output "instrumentation_key" {
   value = azurerm_application_insights.core_application_insights.instrumentation_key
 }
```

Now, I am creating azurerm_api_management_logger and It is require to put the application_insights instrumentation_key value.

FileName: tfapi.tf

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_logger" "example" {
  name                = "example-logger"
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  resource_id         = azurerm_application_insights.example.id

  application_insights {
    instrumentation_key = azurerm_application_insights.example.instrumentation_key
  }
}
```

Just for the information. I am using terraform cloud.

How can I use instrumentation_key from the azurerm_application_insights output?

Comment: Have you tried your current code? What errors do you get?

Comment: Please provide the error message .. your question is not clear ..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of: azurerm_application_insights.**example**.instrumentation_key

Use: azurerm_application_insights.**core_application_insights**.instrumentation_key